# Troubleshoot mongodb connection issues AWS VPC Endpoint

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ssh, atlas

Im facing a problem if connect to my serverless atlas instance using a VPC Endpoint and a Bastion Host. The bastion host are in my VPC and public subnet. With tools like Studio3T, configured to connect using SSH Tunneling, I can connect to the serverless instance using the connection aware string provided by Atlas. I want to know how i can connect to my database using the VPC endpoint from my NodeJS app (Mongoose) in my local environment and SSH Tunnel. The whitelisting its not a problem because its configured to accept connection from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0)

I expect to connect from my local environment with SSH Tunnel or similar to my database (Atlas)

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is. Are you trying something that's not working? Please [edit] your question to describe in detail what you're trying and what happens when you try.